# Adding past and future dates to Firestore/Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Adding the current time is simple:

```js
{
  startDate: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
}
```

However, adding a past or future timestamp is less clear.

How could I add 1 week from now for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it:

```js
const now = moment()
// -> moment format is not compatible until converted toDate
const oneWeekFromNow = now.add(1, 'week').toDate()
const update = {
  endDate: oneWeekFromNow
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can provide a standard JavaScript Date object representing the past or present time.  Firestore will convert that to a Timestamp type field.

```
{
    future: new Date(Date.now() + 60*60*1000),
    future: new Date(Date.now() - 60*60*1000),
}
```

You can also use [Timestamp.fromDate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#static-fromdate) if you need to convert a date to an actual Timestamp object instead, as shown in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#data_types).